# Text not centered on Galaxy S3 Android SDK

Tags: android, android-listview, textview

I am making a simple shopping list app. I have a `ListView` which gets its contents from a database. Now, I just have a simple `TextView` in the middle of the item_list_layout with `gravity` set to `center-vertical` and `left`. Testing the app on my phone works just fine, but on my friends Samsung Galaxy S3, the text doesn't seem to center correctly.

This is how it looks on my HTC One X:

[image]

This is how it looks on my friends Samsung Galaxy S3:

[image]

Does anyone know why this happens and how I can possibly fix it?

EDIT:
XML file of item_list_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="4dp"
android:paddingTop="4dp" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:maxHeight="40dp"
    android:maxWidth="40dp"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:src="@drawable/apptheme_btn_check_off_holo_light" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/item_name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
    android:text="Item"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:textStyle="normal"
    android:typeface="normal" />

</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: can you please post the item_list_layout.xml also are you using any margins?

Comment: can you post your layout xml???

Answer (score 0):

change your textview height

from   `wrap_content` to `match_parent`

Comment: Its not matter if he changed height from wrap_content to match_parent.

Answer (score 0):

Use...

```
android:layout_gravity
```

instead of

```
android:gravity
```

as below...

```
android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
```

**Update:**

To apply `android:layout_gravity`, change `android:layout_height` of `TextView` from `match_parent` to `wrap_content` as below. May be this will help you.

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/item_name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Item"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="normal"
        android:typeface="normal" />
```

Comment: using android:layout_gravity seems not to be working while in the graphical layout it now places the text in the top left corner of the textview.

Comment: please, post full layout xml of list item...then we can't help you properly.

Comment: You can try using `android:gravity="left|center"`.